# how to prevent compilation-scroll-output from coming "unstuck" during recursive edit?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When Emacs enters a `recursive-edit` - for example when entering the minibuffer for a <kbd>M-x</kbd> (AKA `execute-extended-command`) - it seems to remember certain aspects of current state, and restore them if that recursive edit is exited with an error.  Among the bits of state restored is the `(window-point)` of all visible windows.

This means that if you have `compilation-scroll-output` set to `t`, and then:

1. you run `(compile ...)` which is doing its thing, gradually producing output...
2. then you hit <kbd>M-x</kbd> and start to enter an extended command...
3. then you pause a moment to think while a few extra lines of output are produced...
4. then think you think better of that extended command after all, and hit <kbd>C-g</kbd> to cancel it...

what will happen is that the point in your compilation window will jump backwards to the place where it was at the beginning of step 2.  This means that the point in the compilation window is no longer at `(point-max)`, and therefore the window stops scrolling as new output is produced.

I don't know about you, but as I'm using Emacs normally, I tend to make at least a few recursive edits and cancel at least a few of them.  So this means that at some point, my compilation window always comes unstuck, and I have to switch to it and <kbd>M-></kbd> every so often.

Is there a `customize` option to disable this behavior so that the `window-point` stays where it is, or a snippet of elisp which fixes the problem, or even a specific hook which is executed when a recursive edit has been exited, with enough information to tell where the point was before that edit was exited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> does not enter a recursive edit. See the Emacs manual, node `Recursive Edit` for information about recursive edits.
2. What you describe sounds like an Emacs bug. Consider using `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing your recipe (preferably starting from `emacs -Q`).

Comment: Drew, to your first point: yes, it does.  From the documentation you're citing: "Minibuffer input is a special kind of recursive editing."  M-x triggers minibuffer input. `C-]` (AKA `abort-recursive-edit`) while in a `M-x` minibuffer (or a `read-from-minibuffer` or a `completing-read` or any other recursive edit) causes exactly the same effect as `C-g` (AKA `keyboard-quit`) that I am complaining about.

Comment: To your second point: I'm not sure that it is a bug (it makes perfect sense to preserve certain bits of editor state before entering a recursive edit), but even if it is; I use a lot of machines, and I have to live with the Emacs versions that I find on many of them.  I'd really like to find a workaround even if the underlying behavior does eventually change.

Comment: Yes and no. The doc I pointed to is in the Emacs manual.  You refer to the Elisp manual (same node name). Yes, the minibuffer is a kind of recursive editing. No, it is not an ordinary recursive edit. It is parallel to the recursive editing indicated by [[[...]]] in the mode line - each has a separate stack of recursive-edit levels.  But you're also right that the effect is the same wrt what you are complaining about.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug either. But if you file a bug report you'll find out. As you noted clearly, it is a bother in at least some contexts. `M-x report-emacs-bug` is used for enhancement requests, as well as bugs.

Answer (score 1):

That's indeed a bug, and it would be good for you to report it with `M-x report-emacs-bug` so that it may get fixed at some point.  In the mean time, one workaround is to put your *compilation* buffer in a separate frame, since the "save&restore" performed by this minibuffer input only affects the current frame.